# How to generate all attribute combinations from arrays with associated input field in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'im trying to display all combinations of attributes of several arrays with associated price input, for user to fill in. After that, input values are to be saved into database.

For this example, I'm using 3 arrays:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [8] => Small
        [1] => Round
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [6] => 2 Layers
        [4] => 1 Layer
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [10] => no fruit
        [9] => w/ fruit
    )
```

With the following combination function

```
function combination($array, $str = '', $valueKeys = '') {
   $current = array_shift($array);

   if(count($array) > 0) {
       foreach($current as $k => $element) {

           $valueKeys .= $k.'+';
           combination($array, $str.' + '.$element, $valueKeys);
       }
   }
   else{
       foreach($current as $k => $element) {
           $valueKeys .= $k;
           echo '<label>'.substr($str, 3).' + '.$element . '</label> = <input name="attrib_price_'.$valueKeys.'" value="" /><br />' . PHP_EOL;
           $valueKeys = '';

       }
   } 
}
```

HTML Output

```
<label>Small + 2 Layers + no fruit</label> = <input name="attrib_price_8+6+10" value="" /><br />
<label>Small + 2 Layers + w/ fruit</label> = <input name="attrib_price_9" value="" /><br />
<label>Small + 1 Layer + no fruit</label> = <input name="attrib_price_8+6+4+10" value="" /><br />
<label>Small + 1 Layer + w/ fruit</label> = <input name="attrib_price_9" value="" /><br />
<label>Round + 2 Layers + no fruit</label> = <input name="attrib_price_8+1+6+10" value="" /><br />
<label>Round + 2 Layers + w/ fruit</label> = <input name="attrib_price_9" value="" /><br />
<label>Round + 1 Layer + no fruit</label> = <input name="attrib_price_8+1+6+4+10" value="" /><br />
<label>Round + 1 Layer + w/ fruit</label> = <input name="attrib_price_9" value="" /><br />
```

The combinations are all showed, but i have a problem with the price input names, they should include the attribute keys but only the first one is correct (8+6+10). How can I tweak the code to accomplish this?
Suggestions welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the else section You clear the `$valueKeys` that's why only last element is printed in the next iteration Also in the If section you're appending previous iteration's value to `$valueKey`:

```
function combination($array, $str = '', $valueKeys = '') {
   $current = array_shift($array);

   if(count($array) > 0) {
       foreach($current as $k => $element) {
           combination($array, $str.' + '.$element, $valueKeys.$k.'+');
       }
   }
   else{
       foreach($current as $k => $element) {
           echo '<label>'.substr($str, 3).' + '.$element . '</label> = <input name="attrib_price_'.$valueKeys.$k.'" value="" /><br />' . PHP_EOL;
       }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Why not just echoing `attrib_price_'.$valueKeys.$k.'"`?

Comment: I've updated code accordingly second iteration ok, but third iteration shows four ids on input name - <input name="attrib_price_8+6+4+10" value="" /><br />

Comment: edited the answer. Same thing with if clause. Tell me if it doesn't work.